# lwjgl opengl leaving black outlines on textures

Tags: java, eclipse, opengl, lwjgl

my issue is with opengl in java, I have it with the lwjgl.  I am trying to load textures from a .png file and then draw them on to a screen.  The problem I am facing is that when the texture coordinates are selected with glTexCoord2f they are off the texture in some cases.  This manifests its self by leaving large black areas past the edge of the drawn texture.  The only solution that I have found online is to add GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE to the GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S and GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T parameters.  Below is a picture of the textures on a green background with the black boarders.  And then I have the code related to my use of opengl.  Lastly if it matters I am using Eclipse on Linux.  Thank you for any productive answers.

Example
[textures on green background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UJp55.png)
Code: Initializing opengl

```
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(0, width, hight, 0, 1, -1);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
```

Code: Drawing The Textures

```
glClearColor(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    background.bind();
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);  //Draw Background
        glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
        glVertex2i(25, 25);//Upper Left
        glTexCoord2f(1, 0);
        glVertex2i(900, 25);//Upper Right
        glTexCoord2f(1, 1f);
        glVertex2i(900, 600);//Lower Right
        glTexCoord2f(0, 1f);
        glVertex2i(25, 600);//Lower Left
    glEnd();


    statusBarWraper.bind();
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);  //Drawing the wrapper
        glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
        glVertex2i(500, 650);//Upper Left
        glTexCoord2f(1, 0);
        glVertex2i(1000, 650);//Upper Right
        glTexCoord2f(1, 1);
        glVertex2i(1000, 700);//Lower Right
        glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
        glVertex2i(500, 700);//Lower Left
    glEnd();

    statusBar.bind();
    glBegin(GL_QUADS); //Drawing progress Bar
        glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
        glVertex2i(100, 650);//Upper Left
        glTexCoord2f(1, 0);
        glVertex2i(400, 650);//Upper Right
        glTexCoord2f(1, 1);
        glVertex2i(400, 675);//Lower Right
        glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
        glVertex2i(100, 675);//Lower Left
    glEnd();
```

Comment: Try using power of two images, if you have not tried yet.

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly the problem.  Changing all the texture sizes to powers of two solved the problem.